# I'm getting a '500 Internal Server Error' when I try adding menu items

Tags: internal-server-error

For some reason, I suddenly get `500 Internal Server Error` when I try to add menu item to a menu and I can't figure out why.

I'm running Apache2 with Centos 6 OS on a VPS.
I have PHP 5.8 and MySQL 5.1

This is the error message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. (...)

- My error_log file shows nothing.
- I can create new menus
- I can not add pages or custom links to menu items
- I've deleted the .htacess file and get the same error
- I can add new pages and posts

Can anyone help me to figure out what may cause this weird problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this message](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rc32-menus-still-crippled?replies=28) from Mark Jaquith, WP lead developer:

> The WordPress core team is quite aware of this issue, and it is
>   absolutely something that needs to be solved. It is an issue with how
>   the menus are saved. Too much data is passed back. It takes a lot of
>   memory and computation time, and many servers are configured to have
>   limits on the number of vars you can POST in one request.
>   Unfortunately, we just couldn't reach a consensus on the best way to
>   solve it in time for WordPress 3.2. So for this release, it will have
>   to remain a known issue that menu saving performance degrades or
>   generates errors beyond a certain point (which may vary from server to
>   server).
>
> The Trac ticket has been tagged as 3.3-early, which means we'll put it
>   as high priority early in the 3.3 development cycle.
>
> I appreciate your feedback and for holding us to a high standard! This
>   is how things get better.

The question is, when will t his be fixed? :-/

Answer (score 0):

500 Errors are typically .htaccess issues. Regenerate .htaccess and be sure the encoding in your text editor is Unicode No BOM. Or `touch .htaccess` from the shell.

Reupload core WP files and folders.

If that doesn't help, `restart` the box.

If that doesn't help, `yum update` after a backup.

Comment: .htaccess is re-generated when I update permalink structure in WP damin. Restarting does not help. How will `yum update` help?

Comment: Updating Centos might help with a corrupted file. But reupload all core WP files and folders first. And also reboot the VPS.

Comment: Actually it's a known bug. I just found this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rc32-menus-still-crippled?replies=28

Comment: Ah, interesting. How many menu items do you have?

Comment: Around 40 I think.

Comment: It's probably *not* that bug. Try what I suggested. Try raising your php memory allocation and timesouts in php.ini. If you have done no configuration at all to your VPS, you need to; all VPS's begin "plain vanilla" with very basic php (as well as httpd and mysql) configs.

Comment: We tried that, it didn't wotk. It's workign fine on my local computer, but not on staging server and not on production server. Even though it could be something with the server, I still consider it a WP bug when something this basic crashes on one server and not another.

Comment: "It's working fine on my local computer, but not on staging server and not on production server." That's your answer. It may be a bug, but the differences in those servers is triggering it.

Comment: I think we have found the culprit. We have added more memory to the staging server. The problem is that I have deleted a bunch of menus, so I'm not sure if that is why it's working now, or that we increased memory, or both. If it was a memory issue, we should have gotten a error message on this, and not a 500 server error.